# jQuery - value of one select add select how to do that?

Tags: jquery, select, clone

i have script pseudocode:

```
var value = $('#select2').val();
   var i = 0;
 $(this).click(function(){

   if(value == 0){
     $('.kids').css({display: 'none'});
     $('.kid1').css({display: 'none'}).attr("disabled", "disabled");
   }
   else{
     $('.kids').css({display: ''});
     $('.kid1').css({display: ''}).attr("disabled", "");
   }
 });
```

and HTML :

```
<form action="" id="form" method="post">
    <div class="cloned_div">
    <ul>
     <li>Zakwaterowanie</li>
      <li id="input1" class="inputCopy">
    <ul class="selects">
          <li class="label">Set of selects 1</li>
       <li>Select1: 
        ...
       </li>
            <li>Select2: 
                <select name="Select[Ask][1][Children]" id="select2">
                <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
                <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
                <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
                <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
                <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
                </select>
              </li>
                      <li><ul class="kids" style="display:none">
                  <li class="title">Values of perk: </li>
              <li>

               <select name="Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][0]" class="kid1" disabled="disabled" style="display:none">
                 <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
                 <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
                     <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
                 <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
                 <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
               </select>
              </li>
              <li>
               <select name="Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][1]" disabled="disabled" class="kid2" style="display:none">
                 <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
                 <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
                 <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
                 <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
                 <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
               </select>
              </li>
              <li>
               <select name="Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][2]" class="kid3" disabled="disabled" style="display:none">
                <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
                <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
                <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
                <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
                <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
               </select>
              </li>
              <li>
               <select name="Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][3]" class="kid4" disabled="disabled" style="display:none">
                <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
                <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
                <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
                <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
                <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
               </select>
              </li>
            </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>`
```

now is my question:

How can i make that the selected value of `Select[Ask][1][Children]` shows and enables the selects with name `Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][]` so if i select option 1 it'll show the ul with class `kids` and enable select with name `Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][0]`

but if i select option 4 it'll show and enable all four selects etc.

Is it posible to do ?

Comment: It would be better if you could paste only the **relevant** code for **understanding** the problem.

Comment: `new String(..)` - are you a Java programmer? :p

Comment: i've started to play with java for about two days :) and i'm lame in jQuery

Comment: but my script is useless in this case i have no idea how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you posed the question of how to get your code working as part of the comments thread I figured I'd send you a working sample than handles cloning of the elements without duplicating the ID's. Here is a sample using jQuery 1.7.1. If you are using an older version, the .on() event will not work and you will have to switch to the .live() event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* Hide the children selector by default */
        #perksList li.children ul
        {
            display: none;
        }

        //Hides the bullet points
        ul, ul li
        {
            list-style-type: none;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="perksList">
        <li class="perks">
            <label>Choose Perks</label>
            <ul>
                <li class="adults">
                    <label>Adults:</label>
                    <select name="Select[Ask][0][Adults]">
                        <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
                        <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
                        <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
                        <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
                        <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li class="children">
                    <label>Children</label>
                    <select name="Select[Ask][0][Children]">
                        <option label="0" value="0">0</option>
                        <option label="1" value="1">1</option>
                        <option label="2" value="2">2</option>
                        <option label="3" value="3">3</option>
                        <option label="4" value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="title"><label>Value of perk</label></li>
                        <li>
                            <select name="Select[Ask][0][Children][0]">
                                <option value="0" label="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2" label="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3" label="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4" label="4">4 </option>
                            </select>
                        </li>                        
                        <li>
                            <select name="Select[Ask][0][Children][1]">
                                <option value="0" label="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2" label="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3" label="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4" label="4">4 </option>
                            </select>
                        </li>                        
                        <li>
                            <select name="Select[Ask][0][Children][2]">
                                <option value="0" label="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2" label="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3" label="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4" label="4">4 </option>
                            </select>
                        </li>                        
                        <li>
                            <select name="Select[Ask][0][Children][3]">
                                <option value="0" label="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1" label="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2" label="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3" label="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4" label="4">4 </option>
                            </select>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <input type="button" value="Clone" id="btnClone"/>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Store the element as it was when the page was first loaded
        var cloneItem = '<li class="perks">' + $('.perks').clone().html() + '</li>';
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //Using jQuery 1.7.1, the "on" event listens for any new items added.
            //If you're using an older version of jQuery you'll need to use the .live() event
            $(document).on('change', 'li.children > select', function () {
                var parent = $(this).parents('.perks');
                parent.find('li.children ul li select').hide().attr('disabled', 'disabled');

                if ($(this).val() == '0') {
                    parent.find('li.children ul').hide();
                }
                else {
                    parent.find('li.children ul').show();
                    $('li.children ul li select', parent).slice(0, $(this).val()).removeAttr('disabled').show();
                }
            });


            //Handels adding additional rows
            $('#btnClone').click(function () {
                var rowIndex = $('#perksList .perks').length;
                $('#perksList').append(cloneItem);
                $('#perksList .perks:eq(' + rowIndex + ') .adults select').attr('name', 'Select[Ask][' + rowIndex + '][Adults]');
                var listItems = $('#perksList .perks:eq(' + rowIndex + ') .children select');
                listItems.each(function () {
                    var selectIndex = listItems.index(this);
                    if (selectIndex == 0) {
                        $(this).attr('name', 'Select[Ask][' + rowIndex + '][Children]');
                    }
                    else {
                        $(this).attr('name', 'Select[Ask][' + rowIndex + '][Children][' + (selectIndex - 1) + ']');
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thhhis sample helped me to create thhis element. thank you very much

Comment: can some1 tell me one thing how to secure that the value of selects with from Value of perk name example `Select[Ask][0][Children][0]` is removing the bottom selects

Comment: I don't understand what it is you're asking for. Please tried to better word your question and possibly provide an example.

Comment: if i chose in value in the first select after label Value of perk then selects after first select are disabled and hidden. how to avvoid this ?

Comment: @arclite I see what the issue was. The selector was binding the event for all selects in the children node. To fix that I modified the selector to say "direct child" of the children node by adding a ">" charcter. The ONLY line that changes was: $(document).on('change', 'li.children  select', function () { and it changed to $(document).on('change', 'li.children > select', function () {  Answer above was modified to reflect this.

Comment: if i use older version of jquery and change .on() to .live() as you said this four after `Value of perk`selects aren't showing why is that happening ?

Comment: You'll need to read the documentation to see how to use the live event. The parameters you pass LIVE vs ON are different. This is likely why the event isnt firing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I created a JSFiddle. It uses the HTML as you provided with one minor change, I moved the <ul> that houses the children selects inside of the LI that houses the parent. This makes finiding the .kids that belong to that parent easier:

http://jsfiddle.net/MQtkQ/1/

And the HTML :

```
<ul class="selects"> 
    <li class="label">Set of selects 1</li> 
    <li>Select1:  
    ... 
    </li> 
    <li>Select2:  
        <select name="Select[Ask][1][Children]" id="select2"> 
            <option label="0" value="0">0</option> 
            <option label="1" value="1">1</option> 
            <option label="2" value="2">2</option> 
            <option label="3" value="3">3</option> 
            <option label="4" value="4">4</option> 
        </select>
        <ul class="kids" style="display:none"> 
            <li class="title">Values of perk: </li> 
            <li>
                <select name="Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][0]" class="kid1" disabled="disabled" style="display:none"> 
                    <option label="0" value="0">0</option> 
                    <option label="1" value="1">1</option> 
                    <option label="2" value="2">2</option> 
                    <option label="3" value="3">3</option> 
                    <option label="4" value="4">4</option> 
                </select> 
            </li> 
            <li> 
                <select name="Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][1]" disabled="disabled" class="kid2" style="display:none"> 
                    <option label="0" value="0">0</option> 
                    <option label="1" value="1">1</option> 
                    <option label="2" value="2">2</option> 
                    <option label="3" value="3">3</option> 
                    <option label="4" value="4">4</option> 
                </select> 
            </li> 
            <li> 
                <select name="Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][2]" class="kid3" disabled="disabled" style="display:none"> 
                    <option label="0" value="0">0</option> 
                    <option label="1" value="1">1</option> 
                    <option label="2" value="2">2</option> 
                    <option label="3" value="3">3</option> 
                    <option label="4" value="4">4</option> 
                </select> 
          </li> 
          <li> 
            <select name="Select[Ask][1][ChildrenOfChildren][3]" class="kid4" disabled="disabled" style="display:none"> 
                <option label="0" value="0">0</option> 
                <option label="1" value="1">1</option> 
                <option label="2" value="2">2</option> 
                <option label="3" value="3">3</option> 
                <option label="4" value="4">4</option> 
            </select> 
          </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
 $('#select2').change(function(){
      var parent = $(this).parent();
      parent.find('ul.kids li select').css({display: 'none'}).attr('disabled','disabled');

 if($(this).val() == '0'){
     parent.find('ul.kids').css({display: 'none'}); 
  } 
  else {
      parent.find('ul.kids').css({display: ''});
      $('ul.kids li select',parent).slice(0,$(this).val()).removeAttr('disabled').css({display: ''});
  }
 });
```

I myself probably would have put the child class and visibility on the LI instead of the select. I would also have changed the value of all of the hidden selects to 0 so that the values post back as 0 to my form, but thats your call.

Comment: this solution is cool but it isn't work on my server only on jsfiddle i dont know what's wrong. i've copied whole code from jsfiddle and its not working too.

Comment: Did you include the jQuery library? Did you wrap the JavaScript portion in a document ready tag? <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){ /* code here */ });</script> ? Are there any script errors on your page? Did you see the changes I made to your HTML, moving the kids UL/LI tree inside of the same parent LI tag as the select? It works in JSfiddle so without seeing your page I wont be able to tell why it isn't working. Do you have it on avaliable a public URL?

Comment: **[Testing Server](http://mojtalent.dyndns-ip.com/hosting/)** this is my testing url, firebug and dreamweaver doesn't prompted any errors. ive changed only id of second select.

Comment: i've got one last question how can i get that the cloned element wil show that selects as the original select ?

Comment: If I understand your question, you would like to know how to clone the select as it was when the page orginally loaded? I suppose the answer would be to use a variable like var originalSelect = $('#box0').clone(); And any time you want to append an item, you use "originalSelect". I should also point out that you would likely want to add a class to "dziecko0" so you can bind to a class instead of an ID. This would allow you to use the .on() event in jQuery 1.7 so that any items you append also trigger the change event.

Comment: wow i've got it to work but your script doesnt work for cloned element

Comment: **[this is link to working cloning function](http://mojtalent.dyndns-ip.com/hosting/)** this is awesome but function to add selects after chose option works only for first select :(

Comment: You have many issues. The first being that your are keeping all of the same IDs as the original element you're cloning. This is bad form. The second issue as I stated is that jQuery doesn't know anything about elements added to the page AFTER you ran your binder for the change event. You either need to use the .on event to register the change handeler in jQuery 1.7 or use .live in versions prior to 1.7. You also have the option of re-running the change binder on your button click with some slight changes.

Comment: @arclite check out my other answer for a fully working sample